# How to plot a matrix with ggplot

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I wan't to plot a matrix with ggplot.

Here is some sample code:

```
# create a dummy matrix
d2 <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=21,ncol=21,dimnames=list(-10:10,-10:10))
sig <- 3;  mx <- 0; my <- 0;
for (jr in as.numeric(dimnames(d2)[[1]])){
  for (jc in as.numeric(dimnames(d2)[[2]])){
    d2[jr+11,jc+11] <- 1/sig/(2*pi)^.5*exp(-((jr-mx)^2+(jc-my)^2)/2/sig^2)
  }
}

# convert it to dataframe
d2.df <- data.frame(x=rep(as.numeric(dimnames(d2)[[1]]),each=ncol(d2)),y=rep(as.numeric(dimnames(d2)[[2]]),times=nrow(d2)),z=as.vector(d2))

# plot with geom_tiles
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d2.df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Can this be done **without** converting it to dataframe?

Comment: No, not with ggplot2. Yes, with base graphics (e.g., see `help("image")`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly stated in the help of function ggplot that object needs to be a data.frame, hence the question shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this (modified) question since the literal answer is no longer "no" and since the only and very useful answer by amoeba is now [superseded](https://github.com/hadley/reshape)  and there are packages that apperently provide this functionality (e.g. [ggmap::ggimage](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ggmap/html/ggimage.html)).

Comment: @jan-glx I have rolled back your edit because you have completely changed the question in its original meaning. You can ask a new question if you feel that this is appropriate

Comment: @tjebo found one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669634/how-do-i-graph-a-matrix-using-ggplot (has an answer similar to amoeba's one  (more convoluted though))

Answer (score 4):

As Roland comments, no. `ggplot::ggplot()` takes either a `data.frame` or an object than can be run through `fortify()` to create one.

However, your transformation step could be simplified with a call to `reshape2::melt` which does the work of converting `matrix` objects to `data.frame`s. You may be able to find something in `tidyr` that helps here but I haven't looked around in a few years. See:

```r
d2.df <- reshape2::melt(d2, c("x", "y"), value.name = "z")
head(d2.df)
ggplot(data=d2.df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+
  geom_tile()
```

Comment: This doesn't much add to OPs problem: input matrix, output ggplot.

Comment: I agree with you @zx8754.