# How do I graph a matrix using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix

I want to visualize a matrix.

```
MAT <-  matrix(c(100, 7, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, -49), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

> MAT
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  100    7    0
[2,]    0   49    0
[3,]    0    0  -49
```

However, the standard method doesn't shade small numbers properly, and it uses unacceptably-large margins.

```
image(t(MAT[nrow(MAT):1,] ), axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

I want to graph this matrix in `ggplot` using either `geom_raster()` or  `geom_tile()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following function allows you to tweak the colors. By using a color-gradient with the zeros being represented as white, it is easy to detect small numbers as subtle differences from white.

WARNING: `vizMat()` only works for square matrices.

WARNING: `vizMat()` breaks for dim > 99; this has to do with parsing and ordering the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

vizMat <- function(thisMAT) {
  n_max <- dim(thisMAT)[1]
  VNN <- paste0("V", sprintf("%02d",1:n_max))
  df <- rev(as.data.frame(t(thisMAT)))
  names(df) <- VNN
  df %>%
    mutate(row_num = VNN) %>% 
    select(row_num, everything()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-row_num) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=row_num, y=name, fill=value)) +
    geom_raster(show.legend = F) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red",
                         mid = "white",
                         high = "navy", midpoint = .02) +
    theme_void()
}

MAT <-  matrix(c(100, 7, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, -49), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
vizMat(MAT)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `geom_tile()` geometry in `ggplot2` along with `scale_fill_fermenter()`. You can tweak the `breaks` parameter of the scale to have any values that you want for your different break points (adding limits just larger/smaller prevents extra-long categories at the ends of the scales).

```r
graphmat <- function(MAT) {
    mat <- as_tibble(MAT, .name_repair = ~paste0("V", 1:ncol(MAT))) %>%
        mutate(row = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("V"),
                     names_pattern = "V(.+)", names_to = "col") %>%
        mutate(col = as.numeric(col))
    ggplot(mat, aes(x = row, y = col, fill = value)) +
        geom_tile() +
        scale_fill_fermenter(
            breaks = c(-50, -5, 0, 5, 99),
            limits = c(-50.001, 99.001),
            palette = "RdBu"
        ) +
        scale_y_reverse() +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            legend.position = 'top',
            legend.key.width = unit(70, "pt"),
            legend.key.height = unit(10, "pt"),
        )
}

MAT <-  matrix(c(100, 7, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, -49), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
graphmat(MAT)
```

[image: 3x3 matrix colored by cell]

```r
BIGMAT <-  matrix(round(runif(500^2)*100, 2), nrow = 500, ncol = 500)
graphmat(BIGMAT)
```

[image: 500 x 500 matrix colored by value]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, in addition to gaining an intuition on the matrix's structure, I want to  preserve its orientation (you've done that), make efficient use of space (have small margins), and have a meaningful color separation.

Comment: The code also needs to be able to scale to large matrices. Your solution doesn't scale past 10; however, my current solution doesn't scale past 100.

Comment: I really like your use of the .name_repair and names_pattern parameters.  I'm planning on using these as I upgrade my version. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The issue for the number of cells arose because of an incorrect regular expression in the `names_pattern` parameter of `pivot_longer`. It needs to be `names_pattern = `V(.+)` (note the "`+`"). Fixing that, the solution should be big enough to cover very large matrices. I've edited the answer to show both.

Answer (score 0):

What about `heatmap`?

```
heatmap(MAT)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to visualize a matrix to gain intuition on its structure.
To this end, it is important to preserve its orientation, make efficient use of space (have small margins), and  have a meaningful color separation.