# r ggplot2 making basic 2d image

Tags: r, ggplot2

A lot of the functionality of ggplot2 mystifies me, and all the tutorial examples seem to be at a level one higher than where I'm at.

I just want to make a basic raster image, like this:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(625),nrow=25,ncol=25)
image(M,useRaster=TRUE)
```

[image: basic r plot of 2d noise]

How do I do this in ggplot2? I've tried multiple things, but they typically ask for a data frame. If M is converted into a data frame, it gives a different error. I've never really understood the ggplot2 philosophy, or how the package is intended to be used.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68669634/1870254

Answer (score 3):

ggplot2 API works only with `data.frame` objects and one must convert the data to that format to use the package.

In your case I recommend two options to convert the matrix to a data.frame with [tidy format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).

**Original data**

```r
m <- matrix(rnorm(625),nrow=25,ncol=25)
```

**With the `raster` package**

You can easy convert a raster object into a data frame like this

```r
library(raster)
m_df <- as.data.frame(raster(m), xy = TRUE)

m_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

**With tidyverse functions**

You can do this using the tidyverse as well, but the process involves more steps.

```r
library(tidyverse)

m_df <- m %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = 'y') %>%
  pivot_longer(-y, names_to = "x", values_to = "layer") %>%
  mutate(x = parse_number(x))

m_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

Why all those operations:

> They're mostly necessary, especially the pivot_longer part. (One of the downsides of ggplot is that it insists on everything being in long format. In the long run this adds a huge amount of flexibility, but the first step of converting your data to long format can be daunting.) - @Ben Bolker

PS: If you have a considerable amount of images to work with, remember that you can use functional programming. Try to create a function to do de data manipulation and use a loop or another iterating method.

Comment: Is all those operations on new_m necessary to get it to work or are they for the purposes of making it tidy and giving axes labels?

Comment: Changed the answer a bit, now with both approaches. I included @BenBolker comment in the body of the answer. If this does not meet what your were looking for, comment below.